# Does structure of heap changes with GC types in Java? Is it so reference counting, generational and G1 will have a different heap structure?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I was going through the Garbage Collection (GC) topic in Java. I am a bit confused about the heap structure with different GC types. Does the structure of heap changes with GC types in Java?

Comment: Reference counting is not a GC type.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for clarifying. Can you please clarify the same for G1 and generational? As I have read, generational GC divides the heap into 2 parts while the G1 heap divides into small no. of regions.

Comment: When you say heap structure, what exactly are you looking for more details on? For example it's possible that different garbage collectors could represent objects differently. I assume you are not interested in this? Generational collectors typically have the heap in many different parts, each corresponding to objects that have lived for a certain amount of time. Additionally the heap often has parts for preallocating objects. Are you interested in such parts?

Comment: That is correct, G1 is generational with regions. ...and? What is your question?

Comment: I got it G1 is part of generation but I am confused between 2 diagram 
[link](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/images/HeapStructure.png&imgrefurl=https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html&tbnid=5qEIobE0jKHSlM&vet=1&docid=6h-Gzc2L5-1HtM&w=960&h=720&q=g1+vs+cms+jvm&source=sh/x/im)

Comment: and [link](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/G1GettingStarted/images/slide9.png&imgrefurl=https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html&tbnid=8eiSJzURGiZN-M&vet=1&docid=6h-Gzc2L5-1HtM&w=960&h=720&q=g1+vs+cms+jvm&source=sh/x/im) . I Just want to know which is the correct heap structure in java.

Comment: You first link is outdated (there is no permanent generation since Java 8) and it only shows a *logical view*. Older algorithms truly used contiguous regions which resemble the logical view, but for G1GC, the second link’s diagram is closer to the truth. You should [edit] your question to include these points, to make clear what you question is about. “I am bit confused about the heap structure with different GC types” is not even a question.